lauching a linux backgroud process from Azure devops terminates it after 10 seconds
I am launching a background process from Azure devops deployment pipeline using a bash script task.
nohup dotnet <path to the main dotnetapp.dll> 2>&1 &

but on the pipeline I am getting the following message
The STDIO streams did not close within 10 seconds of the exit event from process '/usr/bin/bash'. This may indicate a child process inherited the STDIO streams and has not yet exited.

After this the background process gets terminated.
What is the correct way to do it ?

This is by design. The lifetime of processes in a pipeline are scoped to the pipeline's execution, so the activities in the pipeline are inherently synchronous. For Microsoft's provided cloud-hosted agents, build agents are created and immediately destroyed after the execution has completed -- long-lived processes on the build agent aren't intended for this.
If you need to do something in a script that is asynchronous or multi-threaded, you can certainly do this, but the calling script will need to synchronously monitor the background process until it completes. If the invoking process terminates before the asynchronous operation terminates, your pipeline and all the processes scoped to it will terminate.

I am launching a .net core web api listening on port 5000. We have an on premise Azure devops and build agent running on a redhat linux VM. it was working before but for some reason, it stopped working after the logs on the console were increased significantly.  I understand what you said but I am confused because I am spawning a background process in linux, so the control should come back to the deployment task. Are there any examples on how to do it ?

Nervermind I figured it out. Thank you.

Thanks for your explanation, it makes sense. I understand the lifetime of processes in a pipeline now.
